# Pandas TypeError: no numeric data to plot

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to plot histograms using pandas but I am getting an error that there are no numeric values to plot. here is the code :

```
import pandas as pd


# the x axis tick should be 10 with two histrogram bars side by side on that tick 
y10_a =[2, 2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1] #bar1 (true values) list of size 10
y10_b =[1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1] #bar2 (estimated values) list of size 10

# the x axis tick should be 15 with two histrogram bars side by side on that tick 
y15_a =[2, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1] #bar1 (true values) list of size 15
y15_b =[1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1] #bar2 (estimated values) list of size 15

true =[] # list of true values lists (list of list)
est =[] # list of estimated values lists (list of list)


true.append(y10_a)
true.append(y15_a)

est.append(y10_b)
est.append(y15_b)


# TypeError: no numeric data to plot
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'dataSize':["10","15"], 'true':true, 'estimated':est})
df = df[["dataSize","true","estimated"]]
df.set_index(["dataSize"],inplace=True) # x axis ticks
df.plot.bar(rot=0)
```

For each size, I want to plot a bar that shows the true values with another bar that represents the estimated values next to it.

**Edit:** first I tried with matplotlib but it did not work that is why I switched to pandas. Here is the code using matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
  
X = ['size 4','size 7']
yTrue = [10,20,20,40]
zTrue = [20,30,25,30]
  
yEst = [10,20,20,40,60,42,65]
zEst = [20,30,25,30,59,22,60]

gb =[]
gb.append(yTrue)
gb.append(yEst)

bb = []
bb.append(zTrue)
bb.append(zEst)

X_axis = np.arange(len(X))
for i, j in zip(gb,bb):
    
    plt.bar( i, 0.4, label = 'True')
    plt.bar( j, 0.4, label = 'Estimated')
  
plt.xticks(X_axis, X)
plt.xlabel("Groups")
plt.title("rue vs Estimated")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why are you using pandas for this?

Comment: What's the point of this: `df = df[["dataSize","true","estimated"]]`?

Comment: I could not get matplotlib to work either. in matplotlib it shows 4 separated bars and I found a post that uses pandas to generate two bars per tick

Comment: @Barmar : it was one of my attempts to generate the bars but with it or without it I am still getting the same error

Comment: Maybe you should show how you used `matplotlib`.

Comment: I posted my initial code using matplotlib @BigBen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you wanted to achieve with `pandas`?
[image]

If so:

```py
import pandas as pd

# the x axis tick should be 10 with two histrogram bars side by side on that tick
y10_a = [2, 2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1] #bar1 (true values) list of size 10
y10_b = [1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1] #bar2 (estimated values) list of size 10

# the x axis tick should be 15 with two histrogram bars side by side on that tick
y15_a = [2, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1] #bar1 (true values) list of size 15
y15_b = [1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1] #bar2 (estimated values) list of size 15

true = [] # list of true values lists (list of list)
est = [] # list of estimated values lists (list of list)

true.append(y10_a)
true.append(y15_a)

est.append(y10_b)
est.append(y15_b)

# data-frame creation:
df = pd.DataFrame({'true': [], 'estimated': []})

# add true and estimated values
for c, (true_values, est_values) in enumerate(zip(true, est)):
    for i, (x_t, x_e) in enumerate(zip(true_values, est_values)):
        df.at[i, 'true'] = x_t
        df.at[i, 'estimated'] = x_e

# finally plot
df.plot.bar(rot=0)
```

Basically, the issue is about how you populated the dataframe. You should have an entry for each single value, not an array of them in one single row.